'AADB2C90057: The provided application is not configured to allow the 'OAuth' Implicit flow
I've followed the steps described to configure authentication in a sample web app by using Azure AD B2C (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app?tabs=visual-studio). I can run the app up to step  5.3, but when i click on "sign up/in", i get the following error:
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 00-7dc383f643debddd99a526855bc2dd7b-f993ccb566d654c6-00

Details
Message contains error: 'unauthorized_client', error_description: 'AADB2C90057: The provided application is not configured to allow the 'OAuth' Implicit flow. Correlation ID: c2c20e32-f291-4c91-acad-c1645ef323bb Timestamp: 2024-08-19 11:51:22Z ', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.

© 2022 - WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet

This is the output log:
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44316/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn? - - -
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI.Areas.MicrosoftIdentity.Controllers.AccountController.SignIn (Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[102]
      Route matched with {area = "MicrosoftIdentity", action = "SignIn", controller = "Account", page = ""}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult SignIn(System.String, System.String) on controller Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI.Areas.MicrosoftIdentity.Controllers.AccountController (Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (OpenIdConnect).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[105]
      Executed action Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI.Areas.MicrosoftIdentity.Controllers.AccountController.SignIn (Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI) in 339.5867ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI.Areas.MicrosoftIdentity.Controllers.AccountController.SignIn (Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44316/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn? - 302 0 - 364.4701ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:44316/signin-oidc - application/x-www-form-urlencoded 561
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[12]
      Message contains error: 'unauthorized_client', error_description: 'AADB2C90057: The provided application is not configured to allow the 'OAuth' Implicit flow.
      Correlation ID: 0ea1fec4-a0db-4800-8eb8-7df0a6b16c41
      Timestamp: 2024-08-19 11:53:15Z
      ', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[4]
      Error from RemoteAuthentication: Message contains error: 'unauthorized_client', error_description: 'AADB2C90057: The provided application is not configured to allow the 'OAuth' Implicit flow.
      Correlation ID: 0ea1fec4-a0db-4800-8eb8-7df0a6b16c41
      Timestamp: 2024-08-19 11:53:15Z
      ', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'..
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:44316/signin-oidc - 302 0 - 41.4144ms

It seems error AADB2C90057 is related to the Implicit grant and hybrid flows setting for the app registration, but I believe I've set this correctly to ID Tokens (see screenshot).
Any idea what the issue might be?
Here is my appsettings.json
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://xxx.b2clogin.com",
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "abc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_susi",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_edit_profile",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_reset_password"
    //"CallbackPath": "/signin/B2C_1_sign_up_in",
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}

As is stated here, adding this and a ClientSecret in appsettings.json gets me further down the signin flow, but fails with edit profile flow.
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.Scope.Add(options.ClientId);
});


Make another value in your appsettings called "Tenant" and it should have the exact same value as "Domain". I submitted a Pull Request to fix the issue but it's never been merged.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/pull/764

Thanks for the feedback. On my end, adding a Tenant field in appsettings.json didn't change the behavior. I did try changes proposed here (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/669), but it doesn't solve the other flows. I've modified my initial description accordingly.

That is not necessarily correct - Tenant is a guid while Domain is the configured domain in your app registration.
It can be <tenantname>.onmicrosoft.com if no custom domain is configured, or a custom domain.
